# How to add Approve and disapprove in admin grid Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, custom-admin-grid

***I have already create admin grid in which there is one column status i want to add two functionality Approve and Disapprove which are store in database how can i do that?***

Comment: It would help if you could post your code

Answer (score 1):

> You can add your status field in `InstallSchema.php` file

```
        ->addColumn(
            'status',
            \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_BOOLEAN,
            '',
            ['nullable' => true],
            '0 = Approved, 1= Disapproved'
        )`
```

> You can add status column in `listing.xml`

```
    <column name="status">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Test\Status</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="filter" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Status</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            </item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">6</item>
        </argument>
    </column>
```

> You can add status file here
>   `Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Test\Status`

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Model\Config\Source\Test;

use Magento\Framework\Option\ArrayInterface;

class Status implements ArrayInterface
{
    const STATUS_APPROVE  = 0;
    const STATUS_DISAPPROVE = 1;

    /**
     * @return array
     */
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        foreach ($this->toArray() as $value => $label) {
            $options[] = [
                'value' => $value,
                'label' => $label
            ];
        }

        return $options;
    }

    /**
     * Get options in "key-value" format
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray()
    {
        return [
            self::STATUS_APPROVE => __('Approved'),
            self::STATUS_DISAPPROVE  => __('Disapproved'),
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create mass action to approve or disapprove status in admin grid

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking how to create a mass action with yes no style option.

I literally just coded this about 30 mins ago

So in my example I've added a column to sales admin grid with yes no mass action and a controller to catch yes no value

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoShipment/blob/master/view/adminhtml/ui_component/sales_order_grid.xml#L20-L47

```xml
    <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <massaction name="listing_massaction">
            <action name="status">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">status</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Prevent Auto Ship</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <argument name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">enable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Yes</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="autoshipment/index/massPrevent">
                            <param name="status">1</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="type" xsi:type="string">disable</item>
                        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">No</item>
                        <item name="url" xsi:type="url" path="autoshipment/index/massPrevent">
                            <param name="status">2</param>
                        </item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </action>
        </massaction>
    </listingToolbar>
```

controller logic

https://github.com/DominicWatts/AutoShipment/blob/master/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/MassPrevent.php#L33-L66

```php
/**
     * Execute mass action
     * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        $ids = $this->getRequest()->getPost('selected');
        $status = $this->getRequest()->getParam('status');
        if ($ids && $status) {
            $collection = $this->orderCollectionFactory->create()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', ['in' => $ids]);
            $collectionSize = $collection->getSize();
            $updatedItems = 0;
            foreach ($collection as $item) {
                try {
                    $item->setPreventAutomaticShipment($status);
                    $item->save();
                    $updatedItems++;
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage($e->getMessage());
                }
            }
            if ($updatedItems != 0) {
                if ($collectionSize != $updatedItems) {
                    $this->messageManager->addErrorMessage(
                        __('Failed to update %1 order(s).', $collectionSize - $updatedItems)
                    );
                }
                $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(
                    __('A total of %1 order(s) have been updated.', $updatedItems)
                );
            }
        }
        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        return $resultRedirect->setPath('sales/order/index');
    }
```